# ProGuard warnings for kotlinx.coroutines

Tags: android, proguard, kotlin-coroutines

Recently went through and updated most libraries in our app, which of course has led to ProGuard fun. We've gotten it down to just 3 warnings, which I can't for the life of me figure out what to do about.

Here's the warnings:

```
Warning: kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractContinuation: can't find referenced method 'kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext getContext()' in program class kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractContinuation

Warning: kotlinx.coroutines.DelayKt: can't find referenced method 'kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext getContext()' in program class kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuation

Warning: kotlinx.coroutines.channels.TickerChannelsKt: can't find referenced method 'kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext plus(kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext)' in program class kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher
```

We're using the [recommended set](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/kotlinx-coroutines-android/example-app/app/proguard-rules.pro) of kotlinx.coroutines ProGuard rules:

```
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatcherFactory {}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler {}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidExceptionPreHandler{}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidDispatcherFactory {}

-keepclassmembernames class kotlinx.** {
    volatile <fields>;
 }
```

I've tried various combinations of aggressively keeping or ignoring those classes, but I'll be the first person to tell you that I'm not remotely a ProGuard expert and don't really know what I'm doing.

In general, any over aggressive usage of -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings seems to result in this error message:

```
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
Class       = [kotlinx/coroutines/CommonPool]
Method      = [<clinit>()V]
Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [java/lang/Integer] (with 3 known super classes) and [kotlinx/coroutines/CommonPool] (with 3 known super classes))
Unexpected error while preverifying:
Class       = [kotlinx/coroutines/CommonPool]
Method      = [<clinit>()V]
Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [java/lang/Integer] (with 3 known super classes) and [kotlinx/coroutines/CommonPool] (with 3 known super classes))
```

And any more subtle/targeted methods (i.e. keeping the specific classes that get called back, trying to keep methods, etc) result in no change in the 3 warnings I pasted above.